# how to use php objects?

Tags: php, object

I've work with basic PHP for some time, and there is something I cannot quite figure out.

Let's say I've a database with several real estates, each real estate has its attributes like the ID, price, number of rooms etc etc etc, this info is in one table only. I have in other table (same db) let's say, the map locations for each real estate per ID.

How can I create a script, so that everytime I need to access a real estate full info (different tables) I dont have to make all the queries again, and do something like this:

```
echo realestate->id;
echo realestate->name;
echo realestate->price;
```

also when I call for ex. realestate->id; how do the script knows witch realestate to fetch?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It seems you might need some extra information on how to start using object oriented programming. Please extend your question with what you tried so far and what you've read to try to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too broad a question. Best thing you can do is read these articles:

The short and quick version is that you create a class, within it you define properties that it has, such as variables and/or other objects. Then you can write a function that goes off and gets data from the database (this could be part of a special function called a constructor which gets invoked whenever you create the object). You can create other functions that do all sorts of stuff to the data, such as outputting to a webpage or updating new information and so on.

The more detailed version is in these:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Probably start here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: You may benefit from reading up on database normalisation too.

Comment: @Fluffeh Sorry. I should have directed the comment at Ricardo. I meant it as an addition to your answer. No offence :)